# How to sort items inside a vector

Tags: sorting, vector, rust

I have a vector `[(5, 1), (9, 1), (4, 2)]`

I want it to be sorted as `[(4, 2), (9, 1), (5, 1)]`

Which is sorted in descending order by every second element then the first element.
Would it be possible using `sort_by(|x, y| y.cmp(x))` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
ve.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| (b.1, b.0).cmp(&(a.1, a.0)));
```

Note that I used [`sort_unstable_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable_by), which, in your case, would have the same effect as [`sort_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) but is a bit faster and uses less memory.

Silvio's suggestion could also be slightly optimized by using `sort_unstable_by`:

```
ve.sort_unstable_by(|x, y| y.1.cmp(&x.1).then(y.0.cmp(&x.0)));
```

And here is one more way that comes to mind:

```
ve.sort_unstable_by_key(|k| (-k.1, -k.0));
```

Comment: This is a good approach because Rust already knows how to compare tuples, no need to repeat it. Also, this works for non-Copy types as well: `|a, b| (&b.1, &b.0).cmp(&(&a.1, &a.0))`

Comment: I'd personally go with `ve.sort_unstable_by_key(|&(x, y)| Reverse((y, x)))`, using `std::cmp::Reverse`. Using negation to sort in reverse order seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 6):

It is most certainly possible, and you have the right idea using `sort_by`. You can sort by the second element in basically the way you suggest.

```
sort_by(|x, y| y.1.cmp(&x.1))
```

This solves the first part of your problem. To handle the tiebreaker, we want to be able to say "if the second element is the same, then go by the first element", and in fact Rust has a method that does exactly this: [`Ordering::then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then).

```
sort_by(|x, y| y.1.cmp(&x.1).then(y.0.cmp(&x.0)))
```

Note: This will evaluate both orderings in every case, which is probably fine. If your comparison function is unusually expensive, you might consider [`then_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then_with) instead, which takes a closure rather than a value as its argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsIwFAX3nuK1C/kfQmhEFyriUURLxEITS/obGtqePRbU1cAwE4Zecn56uHvjiTFtgNYK3CCIuCDauiA6KBhWoOOPe4Ud83lto@7fQW6PRPOokGYkbXTtOtqO2rCWl/WUdPVXFX@3LjReWl9QOZ2uS6kQV73k/AE)

Comment: When using `Copy` types, I'd recommend using `v.sort_by_key(|&(_, x)| std::cmp::Reverse(x));` instead, which is clearer. (For non-`Copy` types, `sort_by_key` has some issues with lifetimes and would be harder to use)